# Multiple intersection comparisons with conditional filters for edges and node colours in networkx?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, networkx, intersection

I have 4 data files that I want to compare to produce a weighted network with colour coded nodes in NetworkX.
I have a base dataset which looks like this (note: all product codes in all datasets are strings):

```
year    value    location_code    product_code
1995    0        ABC              0101
1995    1500     DEF              0101
1995    2000     GHI              0101
1996    1000     ABC              0102
1996    0        DEF              0102
1996    3000     GHI              0102
...    ...       ...              ...
2015   0         ABC              9050
2015   9000      DEF              9050
2015   9800      GHI              9050
2016   5000      ABC              9060
2016   0         DEF              9060
2016   4000      GHI              9060
```

I then have a specific list of product codes which I am interested in within that dataset like this:

```
product_code
0102
0104
0110
...
2450
4590
9060
```

the total number of unique products in this list is shorter than the total number of unique products in the original list.

Then I have a dataset comparing different products with one another with weights between them like this:

```
product_1    product_2    weight
0101         0102         0.0000
0101         0103         0.4560
0101         0104         0.6790
0102         0101         0.0000
0102         0103         0.9850
0102         0104         0.3670
...          ...          ...
9050         9051         0.7890
9050         9052         0.2340
9050         9053         0.2789
```

and finally I have a set of values associated with each node for determining the colour which looks like this:

```
product    value
0101       -0.471
0102       -0.678
0103        0.532
...         ...
9050        1.306
9051       -1.900
9052        0.678
```

I want to produce a colour coded network of the nodes associated with the intersection of the list of products at a given location in a particular year and the specific list of codes I am interested in. Then I want to filter the weighted product pairs to just those associated with the products appearing at that intersection and finally I want to assign the colours of the nodes in that network to the values in the final dataset.

So far I have tried doing this:

```
df_prod_at_loc = pd.read_file('product_location_data.file', columns = ['year', 'value', 'location_code', 'product_code'

df_specific_prods = pd.read_file('specific_prods.file', dtype={'product_code': str})

df_weight_data = pd.read_file('weight_data.file', dtype={'product_1': str, 'product_2': str, 'weight': float})

df_node_values = pd.read_file('node_values.file', dtype={'product': str, 'value': float})

unique_specific_prods = (df_specific_prods['product_code'])
unique_specific_prods_list = list(dict.fromkeys(unique_specific_prods)
unique_specific_prods_list = sorted(unique_specific_prods_list)

location_prod_codes = df_prod_at_loc.drop(columns=['year'])
location_prod_codes = location_prod_codes.groupby(['location_code'])
lcprodcodes = location_prod_codes.agg(func=list)
lcprodcodes = lcprodcodes.drop(columns=['value'])
lcprodcodes = lcprodcodes['product_code'].apply(lambda row : sorted(list(set(row))))
lcprodcodes = lcprodcodes.DataFrame(lcprodcodes)
dict_lcprodcodes = lcprodcodes.to_dict()
dict_lcprodcodes = dict_lcprodcodes['product_code']

location_list = ['ABC', 'GHI']

location_products_dict = {k: v for k, v in dict_lcprodcodes.items() if k in location_list}
current_list = location_products_dict['ABC'] #Can be changed manually to select from location_list

specific_prods_at_loc = sorted(set(current_list).intersection(unique_specific_prods_list))

specprod_idx = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(unique_specific_prods_list)}

df = df_weight_data[df_weight_data.product_1.isin(specprod_idx) & df_weight_data.product_2.isin(specprod_idx)
df.to_csv('df.csv')
df = pd.read_csv('df.csv', dtype={'product_1': str, 'product_2': str, 'weight': float})

unique_specific_prods_at_location = (df['product_1'])
unique_specific_prods_at_location = list(dict.fromkeys(unique_specific_prods_at_location))
unique_specific_prods_at_location = sorted(unique_specific_prods_at_location)

df_specific_prod_node_values = df_node_values[df_node_values.product,isin(specprod_idx)]
df_specific_prod_node_values = df_specific_prod_node_values[['product', 'value']]

prodlist = list(df_specific_prod_node_values['product'])
valuelist = list(df_specific_prod_node_values['value'])

values_dict = {}
row = 0
for name in prodlist:
    values_dict[name] = valuelist[row]
    row = row + 1

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(unique_specific_prods_at_location)

row = 0
for c in df['product_1']:
    p = df['product_2'][row]
    w = df['weight'][row]
    if w > 0:
        G.add_edge(c,p, weight=w, with_labels=True)
    row = row + 1

colour_map = values_dict
values = [colour_map.get(node,0 for node in G.nodes()]

pos = nx.kamada_kawai_layout(nx.minimum_spanning_tree(G))

plt.figure(1)
nx.draw(nx.minimum_spanning_tree(G), pos=pos, node_color=values, node_size=150, font_size=10, with_labels=True)

plt.show()
```

So this code is sort of working, in that I can produce the desired diagrams with the correct colour changes for nodes and approximately correctly specified connections (I say approximately because I don't know how to check for certain, but it looks right). An example of what this looks like can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfX3x.png

But when I try to reproduce this diagram for different locations in different years, the number of nodes sometimes changes and sometimes stays the same, e.g. locations ABC and GHI might both have exactly 172 nodes 20 years apart (i.e. ABC-1995=172, GHI-1995=172, ABC-2015=172, GHI-2015=172), which doesn't seem right as I would have expected this value to change more over time. Other locations, like DEF might have 54 in 1995 and 97 in 2015. So it seems that this is working sometimes and other times not working? But I cannot fathom why. I appreciate this is a long post and thank you for reading this far if you have done. There is probably a far easier way to do this than what I have attempted, so any suggestions for improving this code are welcome. Why might the values change for some locations over many years and not for others? I am expecting the values to change pretty consistently for all locations and all years.

Comment: I would strongly recommend writing some tests with data for which you know the correct answers. This will probably involve creating several fake datasets to test different aspects of your code. At the moment, you don't even know for certain if there is a problem, and if so, whether the problem is with your code or your data or both.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I performed some tests and found out there is actually nothing wrong with the code, I'm just being dumb

Comment: Don't beat yourself up about it. It is very common to have fishy looking results and not knowing if there is actually a problem and if so where it is coming from. That's why it is recommended practice to write tests, tests, and more tests.